# Missing template error when splitting view from layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using St. Laurent & Edd Dumbill's Learning Rails book.  I am getting a missing template error when doing splitting view from layout exercise in chp3 above.

Please help me understand why the error below is occurring.

Template is missing
Missing layout layouts/hello.html.erb in view path C:/Instantrails/rails_apps/hello/app/views

Controller info:
Name: hello_controller

Path: C:\INSTAN~1\rails_apps\hello\app\controllers

Code:

```
class HelloController <ApplicationController

def index
@message="Hello!"

@count=3

@bonus="This message came from the controller."
end
```

end

View Info:

Name: index.html

Path: C:\INSTAN~1\rails_apps\hello\app\views\hello

Code:

```
<h1><%=h @message %></h1>
<p>This is a greeting from app/views/hello/index.html.erb</p>
<% for i in 1..@count %>
<p><%= @bonus %></p>
<% end %>
```

Name: hello.html.erb

Path: 
C:\INSTAN~1\rails_apps\hello\app\views\layouts

Code:

```
<html>
<head><title><%=h @message %> </title>
<% stylesheet_link_tag 'hello' %>

</head>
<body>
(using layout)
<!--layout will incorporate view-->
<%= yield :layout %>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please go ahead and learn about debugging a rails application http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check all your file names. I just copied these three files into my test project (rails 4) and it seems to be working fine. You are missing a closing 'end' in the controller class (probably just a copy&paste error).

Comment: My erb file format was not correct. My mistake was that I created the erb file from notepad because I didnt know how to create it in instantrails manually.  To fix my problem I copied my index.html file from hello\app\views folder to the layouts directory.  I then renamed the file and copied the code above into it. I do not think I would have had this problem if I used scaffolding.  Unfortunately that lesson is for chp 5 in my book.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have forgotten to include the layout name in controller file :

```
class HelloController  < ApplicationController

 layout "Hello" 

 def index
  #your code goes here.
 end
```

that layout section will look for app/views/Layouts/hello.html.erb.